# cannot open sas file: table does not exists error

Tags: file, sas, dataset

I'm trying to open a sas file(.sas7bdat) that created a year ago. The file is only 128KB. Usually I just double click it, but it shows table does not exist. And I tried open it in sas, but after creating its sas library. The dataset is not there either. 
Does that mean the file is damaged? How can I open that file? 
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: It may just have zero observations. What's the exact error it gives you?

Comment: no, I opened in txt, and there is data in it.

Comment: Did you change the filename to use uppercase letters?  SAS wants dataset filenames to be in lowercase letters.  Is it in a folder with datasets from an older version of SAS?  Perhaps the libref was created using the wrong engine so that it would not see the sas7bdat files.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it by opening with SPSS and then export it to CSV file. 
I'm guessing probably the file was created as other sas format, and then manually set as sas7bat format.